# Determine the affine varieties morphism from homomorphism of k algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $A=k[x_1,...,x_m]/I, B=k[y_1,...,y_n]/J$ be two finitely generated $k$-algebra. Let

\begin{align*}
\phi:&A\rightarrow B\\
&x_i\mapsto s_i(y_1,...,y_n)
\end{align*}

be a $k$-algebra morphism.
Then there is a corresponding morphism

\begin{align*}
f:\operatorname{Spec} B&\rightarrow \operatorname{Spec} A\\
(\tilde {y}_1,...,\tilde{y}_n)&\mapsto (t_1,...,t_m)
\end{align*}
where $t_i$'s are polynomials in the variables $\tilde {y}_j$. Here we only look at the maximal ideals and we identify the maximal ideals with the corresponding closed points. I know the morphism $f$ is obtained by pulling back the maximal ideal under $\phi$, but that does not operate straightforwardly for me. I am wondering are there some general steps (or tricks) one can take to write out the $t_i$'s without going through the pulling back ideal process.

Comment: $t_i=s_i$. There's nothing else that could happen.

Comment: @KReiser Oh, that’s quite simple. I overthought about the problem. Thank you.